# Actualizar "compile" en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy empezando con la creación de aplicaciones android, anteriormente había entrado a un curso donde realizábamos aplicativos para android, intente abrir uno de los ejercicios para practicar mas pero al momento de abrirlo me aparecían errores del `Gradle`, esto por las compilaciones y sus versiones.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar las compilaciones?

tengo varios compile y me marcan errores, y aunque le de en `install repository and sync project` no hace nada y el problema persiste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la versión de build que tengo y el targetSDKVersion

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mx.com.dtss.carritocompras"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto antes te ha funcionado? Lo pregunto porque dices que lo has sacado de un ejercicio. Ves al fichero build.gradle, escribe un espacio desùés de cualquier línea y arriba te pedirá que sincrinices, dale ahí y déjalo sincronizar. Si no te funciona pon el contenido de tu fichero build.gradle

Comment: Lo que necesitas instalar es lo definido en el bloque dependencies { ...  } de tu archivo build.gradle, agregué respuesta.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano perdon por apenas responder pero si, anteriormente me funcionaba correcto, pero hace unos dias dejo de funcionar y me comenzo a marcar los errores y aunque le de clic en install repository no genera ninguna accion ni inicia ningun instalador

Answer (score 1):

Si tu archivo build.gradle es el que has puesto, el error que te marca es que te falta añadir las dependencias, aquí te dejo una página donde te enseña lo que son:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Te pongo un ejemplo de un fichero build.gradle mio:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 10       
    versionName "1.9"  
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.8'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Después del buildTypes es donde le indicas los "paquetes" que vas a utilizar y que tienes que descargar, que es lo que te falla a ti. Yo utilizo los que me hacen falta, tendrás que buscar los tuyos.

Uno de tus errores dice:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
```

Tendrás que escribir el compile correspondiente para descargar esa librería, yo como uso la 7.21.03 tengo que poner esto:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo puedo actualizar las compilaciones?

Lo que se requiere son dependencias y una opción es simplemente dar clic a los enlaces, de esta forma instalarías las dependencias necesarias definidas en tu `build.gradle`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No olvides sincronizar tu proyecto con los archivos gradle nuevamente.

Comment: claro que he intentado intalarlos (perdon por apenas responder) pero al dar click sobre install repository no genera ninguna accion y el problema persiste

Comment: Es raro que no genere ninguna acción, tu build.gradle entonces no tiene especificadad las dependencias, el build.gradle que especificas en tu pregunta es todo?